# SQL find nearest number

Tags: sql, oracle10g

Say I have a table like the following (I'm on Oracle 10g btw)

```
NAME    VALUE
------  ------
BOB     1
BOB     2
BOB     4
SUZY    1
SUZY    2
SUZY    3
```

How can I select all rows where `value` is closest to, but not greater than, a given number.  For example if I want to find all the rows where value is closest to 3 I would get:

```
NAME    VALUE
------  ------
BOB     2
SUZY    3
```

This seems like it should be simple... but I'm having no luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT name, max(value)
FROM tbl
WHERE value <= 3
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Thank you!! I had my group by wrong for I don't know how long now >:|

Answer (score 1):

This works ([SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c35ba/5)):

```
SELECT name, max(value)
FROM mytable
WHERE value <= 3
GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on hagensofts answer:

```
SELECT name, max(value) 
FROM tbl 
WHERE value <= 3 AND ROWNUM <=2
GROUP BY name
```

With ROWNUM you can limit the output rows, so if you want 2 row, then you can limit the rownum.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH v AS (
  SELECT 'BOB' NAME, 1 value FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'BOB', 2 FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'BOB', 4 FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'SUZY', 1 FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'SUZY', 2 FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'SUZY', 3 FROM dual
)
SELECT *
  FROM v
 WHERE (name, value) IN (SELECT name, MAX(value)
                          FROM v
                         WHERE value <= :num
                      GROUP BY name)
;
```